# Unique url slugs (routes)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, unique, slug

Suppose i have this db table schema:

```
id |      article          | slug
1    hey guys how are you?  hey-guys-how-are-you?
```

I'm trying keeping my db route field unique

route is always the message field camelized like this `this-is-a-title-but-now-is-a-route`

so inserting the same route produce a `db error of duplicated key`

so which is a good practice to control and insert always unique routes?

thanks

Comment: WordPress for example would create page slugs like `this-is-my-route-1`, `this-is-my-route-2`, ...

Comment: @biziclop yep and how to control that? which is the logic behind the +1 , +2 , +3 .. etc?

Comment: do you control if exist then put +1 then control if exist again put +2 then so on .. OR else?

Comment: obviously your route component isn't unique. keep only the id unique, and use it in your route (maybe like SO does?).

Comment: @didierc nope :( i have clear url like **project/-my-project** :( don't wnat to turn to **project/8374/my-project** pleaseeee :D

Comment: no problem, adding a number at the end is the clear url solution you need then.

Comment: well i found good to add sme increment at the end of the slug, it will be only when necessary, in all other cases(majority) i will anyway have clean urls ;) thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you've tagged CodeIgniter, I would suggest pre-checking the value of the slug field, then increment the value if need be. The CI [string helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/string_helper.html) has a `increment_string` function that will take care of that for you.

`increment_string()`

Increments a string by appending a number to it or increasing the number. Useful for creating "copies" or a file or duplicating database content which has unique titles or slugs.

Usage example:

```
echo increment_string('file', '_'); // "file_1"
echo increment_string('file', '-', 2); // "file-2"
echo increment_string('file-4'); // "file-5"
```

So

`this-is-a-route` becomes `this-is-a-route-1`

and

`this-is-a-route-1` becomes `this-is-a-route-2`

etc.

Comment: great thanks for the CI tips, but the problem is really not to add an increment, it is the logic behind, i mean, control if exist then put it if needed, but what if i have **-my-route-** then **-my-route-1** in db? if i try to insert again **-my-route-** this should become **-my-route-2**

Comment: It's easy to check if `-my-route-n` exists with a sql `LIKE` comparison and `ORDER BY` slug. For example: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE slug LIKE '-my-route-%' ORDER BY slug DESC LIMIT 1` -> this should give you the highest '-my-route-n` available and you can run this through the `increment_string` function.

Comment: well this is easy but not performant, what if you have thousands of db records? a sql LIKE will be too expensive for just controlling/inserting a slug, don't you think? :P

Comment: Unless you're indexing your `slug` field, which I would assume you are, being that this is a unique field and used for accessing the record.

Comment: uhmm ... uhmm .. :P well, definitely could be a solution, but i'm afraid about LIKE operator :P mmm

Comment: actually i'm thinking about going for your solution.. i check this , thanks!

Comment: the `LIKE` operator will use indexes for the part of the term up to the first wildcard. Because your sql statement uses the wildcard at the end of the term, the index should perform as well as a `=` comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of php's [uniqid](http://php.net/uniqid) and perhaps with more entropy to do the job for you.

The return value of this function is always of same length. Using more entropy its 23 and 13 otherwise. So you can easily substr the slug to get actual thing whenever you want.

Comment: this sounds great and if no more answers i'll check this surely

Comment: sorry man, swatkins conviced me at the end :P , thank you so much anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This method make a loop to increment the slug until it find an non unexistant one.

In your model:

```
public function create_slug($title) {
    $this->ci->load->helper('string');
    $this->ci->load->helper('url');

    $i = 1;
    $max = 10; 
    $slug = url_title($title, '-', TRUE);

    while($i <= $max && ($exist = $this->db->where('slug', $slug)->count_all_results('posts')) != 0) {
        $slug= increment_string($slug, '-');
        $i++;
    }

    //max was reached and the last slug is not unique
    if($i >= $max && $exist > 0) return FALSE;

    return $slug;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But for me it's not run by public. So i improved it for you.